# Almost Everywhere Convergence of Walsh Series of $L^2$ functions

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am currently reading the Hunt's papar (http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.2/Main/icm1970.2.0655.0662.ocr.pdf), and am wondering if there is any notes which presents his argument more comprehensively.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There are many accounts of this:

1. Thiele's transactions article "[The quartile operator and pointwise convergence of Walsh series](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1695038)."
2. Thiele's [Book Wave Packet analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821836617).
3. Tao's [wave packet course notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.01w/)
4. Demeter's recent article "[A guide to Carleson's Theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0886)"
5. This article of Gosselin ("[On the convergence of Walsh-Fourier series for $L^2(0,1)$](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=546808)).
6. Billard's original article (in French) "[Sur la convergence presque partout des séries de Fourier-Walsh des fonctions de l'espace $L^2(0,1)$](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=217510)"

While Hunt and Billard's arguments are closer to Carleson's original approach to the subject, the first four sources above are closer to the Lacey-Thiele-type arguments. The article of Gosselin follows Fefferman's approach.